# Count post views in loop

Tags: loop, count, views

I'm trying to show the post views for every post on a blog page (so in a loop).

I tried it with the following code in the functions.php:

```
  // function to count views.
function setAndViewPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'views';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
    return $count; /* so you can show it */
}
```

Then in the loop function I used this code:

```
<?php echo setAndViewPostViews(get_the_ID());  ?>
```

However, every post gets a count added every time the blog page is reloaded, strange thing is that the id is different for every post. How can I make this it will only count the every posts? And, if possible, how would I make it so that it only counts every individual views?

Thanks in advance!

Btw. I know there are a lot of plugins that do this, it's not my intention to use one, so please don't suggest a plugin.

Comment: Have you looked at `is_single()` or `is_singular()` to restrict the counter updates?

Comment: None, I'm trying to put this in a plugin. I've put the
`<?php echo setAndViewPostViews(get_the_ID());  ?>` under this while loop:

`<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    session_start(); `

Answer (score 2):

**Few remarks:**

- You should consider using a *prefix* on your meta key, for example `lars_views`, to minimize the risk of other plugins messing around with it.
- If you want to hide it from the *edit screen*, you can use an *underscore*: `_lars_views`.
- Consider wrapping the part of your code, that updates the counter, with `if( is_single() ){...}`. This will restrict it to single post views. [More about this conditional tag in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single). If you have custom post types, consider `is_singular()`.
- You start the counter with `0`, but I think it would be more accurate to start with `1` instead when you use `is_single()`.
- You can use `update_post_meta()` instead of `add_post_meta()`,  if you want to simplify your code. [Check out the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta),
- I would rather have a seperate function to show the counts and another one to update the counter via some *hook*. I think it's more flexible.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setAndViewPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'views';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);

    // Check if the post has already been viewed by the current visitor
    $viewed_key = 'viewed_' . $postID;
    $viewed = isset($_COOKIE[$viewed_key]) ? true : false;

    if (!$viewed) {
        if ($count == '') {
            $count = 0;
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        } else {
            $count++;
            update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
        }

        // Set a cookie to mark the post as viewed by the current visitor
        setcookie($viewed_key, $postID, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
    }

    return $count;
}

<?php echo setAndViewPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

Comment: Please introduce your code in some way to help the OP, like summarizing the changes that were made, and whether the code is tested or untested.